# Vue: From inside function, how to wait for another function to finish?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In the code below, when `newFlow` is true, I emit an event to the root of the app to fire `GetIDFromNewFlow()` .  That functions makes an Axios request to get data from an endpoint and sets the response to a data instance called `IDDataPiece`.  The `emitcheckout` event triggers a function in the root to handle the checkout and it's dependent on that `IDDataPiece` that is set once the response of the first emitted event comes back but the problem is it's coming back too late so the 2nd emitted event is hung up waiting.
I thought the `setTimeout` would resolve it, and it does at times, but it's inconsistent and I'd rather not make the setTimeout a large amount of time just to be safe because that feels sloppy.

```
checkout: function(card) {

    if (this.newFlow) {

        this.$emit('emitgetidfromnewflow');
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        let orderId = null;

        let data = {
            cardId: cardId,
            orderId: orderId
        }

        this.$emit('emitcheckout', data)
    }, 2000)

},
```

Comment: You can use async/ await !
Check this https://hackernoon.com/lets-make-a-javascript-wait-function-fa3a2eb88f11

Comment: Dispatching a Vuex action would be perfect for this. Emitting events only works one way (inside -> out) so you cannot get information about event handles from within your component

Comment: thanks @Phil .  I'd love to have that as an option and I wish we had Vuex but that's something we'll be adding at my company in about 2 months.  I keep telling them they should have started the project with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misusing events.

An event (in general) is a way of notifying the outside world that something has happened to you. As an example consider native browser DOM events, things like `click` and `blur`. It might be that these events are completely ignored but they provide the opportunity for code to run when something happens to a DOM element.

When emitting events from a Vue component the idea is the same. Something has happened to the component (or is about to happen to the component) that might be of interest elsewhere.

It's not uncommon for a component to need to do some stuff internally as well as firing an event. That's fine, a component should handle whatever responsibilities it has and then fire an event to let external observers do their thing. The component is not responsible for what those external observers do, that's their problem.

It's important to appreciate responsibilities here. When a component emits an event it is not responsible for what the observer does with that event. The observers might not even exist.

So, for example, if you've got a button emitting a `click` event, the button's responsibility ends with emitting the event. If nothing is listening for that event then nothing will happen, which is almost certainly a bug. But that bug isn't the button's problem.

Events shouldn't be used in place of method calls. If a component is responsible for ensuring that a specific thing happens then it should call a method to make that happen. Events should not be emitted to tell something else to do something, they should be used to notify observers that something has happened to it. This is nuanced as in a lot of cases a component is only used in one place and an event only has one listener, so the event seems equivalent to a method call.

So, going back to the code in the question, it would seem that `emitgetidfromnewflow` is not a proper event in the sense that I have described above. That seems to be a workaround to make sure a particular method gets called. Perhaps this is a legitimate event from the perspective of this component but the name implies otherwise.

The `emitcheckout` event on the other hand does seem to be a proper event. It's something that has happened to this component. Obviously the action of checking out is not yet complete from a user's perspective but as far as this component's responsibility goes it's done with it. Whatever else might be required is not its problem, that's for any observers to handle.

So, to get your code working, the first step is to establish what the real events are here. Making sure those events are handled correctly is not this component's responsibility, so the timer should definitely go. Whatever is listening for the events will need to keep track of what's going on and whether one thing needs to wait for another. Chances are there'll be some promises involved and you'll need to wait for one promise to resolve before dealing with the second event.

If you think that responsibility should remain within this component then the first event is probably not appropriate. Instead make a method call. Most likely that method call would return a promise so you can then wait for that before emitting the real event.

As a final thought, you may want to consider using Vuex rather than getting tied into knots with events on a root.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle for the in depth explanation and response!  That's confusing because I was taught to call a function of the parent, it should be emitted and that the use of `$emit` was better than accessing the function by doing `$parent.functionName()`  incase the component is used elsewhere, `$parent` would have to change.

Comment: @burtonLowel I am definitely not advocating using `$parent` here. When I talked about calling a method I didn't mean using `$parent.functionName()`. That is, indeed, even worse than using an event. More likely such a method would be a store action, though there are many possible options here, e.g. passing a callback via a prop. Figuring out where the boundaries and responsibilities lie is not something I can really do for you, I was just trying to give a feel for what appropriate use of events looks like. I don't have anything like enough information to provide a specific recommendation.